# Get a list of all files from my dropbox account using DropNet API

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dropnet

```cs
private void LoadContents()
{
    App.DropNetClient.GetMetaDataAsync("/", (response) =>
    {
        _model.Meta = response;
    },
        (error) =>
        {
            //OH DEAR GOD WHAT HAPPENED?!
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            });
        });
}
```

I am using above code but getting null as response, here how can I get the response?

Comment: See if this [issue](https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet/issues/40) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check what version of the RestSharp nuget package do you have in your project. I had issues and found they were resolved by updating RestSharp to 104.4.0.